# How would i store unknown amount of data in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have online store that has simple products ( 1 product has 1 price and 1 color and 1 field for bought count ).
How i want to extend that is to have ( 1 product has X price's and X colors and bought count for each of colors seperated ).
So the regular approach to have specific count of fields for all values doesn't work here.

So my question: How would i store unknown count of prices and colors for 1 product and also bought count for each type of that product?

Do i serialize data from php and store it in BLOB field type? What would be suggested or industry standart way of doing this sort of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read up on relational databases, as it is an industrial standard. In your example, you could have one table with a certain `ProductID`, and your subsequential tables will reference their own rows of data to a certain `ProductID` through a reference table.

Here is a very basic example of how you could have a product articulate to multiple colors.

```
Products (table 1)
------------------
ProductID (int 20)
ProductName (varchar 250)
Description (text)
ProductPrice (float)

ProductToColor (table 2)
------------------------
ProductID (int 20)
ColorID (int 20)

Color (table 3)
----------------
ColorID (int 20)
ColorName (varchar 250)
Description (text)
```

A very basic SQL to get all the colors that are under a specific product ID would be:

```
SELECT ProductID,Color.* FROM Products LEFT JOIN ProductToColor ON Product.ProductID = ProductToColor.ProductID LEFT JOIN Color ON ProductToColor.ColorID = Color.ColorID WHERE Product.ProductID = "1";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create a separate `ProductColor` table with `ProductId`, `Color`, and `Price` columns and one row per color per product.